# How to disable julia package warning suppression?

Tags: julia, package-management

Scenario:

```
    Warning: <PACKAGE-A> does not have <PACKAGE-B> in its dependencies:
    ...
    Loading <PACKAGE-B> into <PACKAGE-A> from project dependency, futuree warnings for <PACKAGE-A> are suppressed.
```

After adding <PACKAGE-B> into dependencies section of Project.toml of <PACKAGE-A>, throws another missing dependency warning and suppresses further missing dependencies.

Please guide me in disabling the suppression of warnings to get fine/granular logs for better debugging.

Comment: I've also had the same warnings, and I don't quite understand them. I get this warning even though I do have `<PACKAGE-B>` in the Project.toml and Manifest.toml files. Do you have `<PACKAGE-A>` in `dev` mode?